# Given an index in a flattened list, get the index of the original list item

Tags: python

I begin with a list of words like `["ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR"]`.

Later, I flatten the list to make a string: `"ONETWOTHREEFOUR"`. I do some stuff while looking at this string and get a list of indices, say `[6,7,8,0,4]` (which maps onto that string to give me the word "THROW", though as pointed out in comments that's irrelevant to my question).

Now I want to know which items from the *original list* gave me the letters I am using to make my word. I know I used letters `[6,7,8,0,4]` from the joined string.

Based on that list of string indices, I want the output `[0,1,2]`, because indexes `6`, `7` and `8` in the flattened string fall within the word at index `2` in the original list, index `0` comes from the word at index `0`, and index `4` falls within the word at index `1`. My output doesn't include `3`, because none of the indices I used fall within the final four-character word.

What I've tried so far:

```py
wordlist = ["ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR"]
stringpositions = [6,7,8,0,4]
wordlengths = tuple(len(w) for w in wordlist) #->(3, 3, 5, 4)
wordstarts = tuple(sum(wordlengths[:i]) for i in range(len(wordlengths))) #->(0, 3, 6, 11)

words_used = set()
for pos in stringpositions:
    prev = 0
    for wordnumber,wordstart in enumerate(wordstarts):            
        if pos < wordstart:
            words_used.add(prev)
            break
        prev = wordnumber
```

It seems awfully long-winded. What's the best (and/or most Pythonic) way for me to do this?

Comment: You forgot to mention if it works or not

Comment: @TimCastelijns you know I thought it did, but it turns out it doesn't. My code is currently wrong but I know that I can get that method to work. It just seems long-winded, as I said.

Comment: Actually, I think it does work. I don't even know any more. I hate nested loops.

Comment: Based only on the example given, how do you expect to get a single unambiguous answer, the string `THROW` could have equally been constructed using the `O` from `FOUR` instead of from `ONE`, in which case the answer would be `{1,2,3}`

Comment: @DanLenski yes, but for my purposes here, I already know which letters I used. In this case it's `[6,7,8,0,4]`, as I wrote in my question. I'll edit to make that clearer.

Comment: @Sam: Okay, so the goal is to figure out which words were used based on which **letter positions** were used, rather than which **letters** were used? You may want to rewrite the question to clarify this.

Comment: @DanLenski I have edited the question but I'm struggling to find the perfect wording! I hope it's a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clarified [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31347414/map-string-positions-to-list-positions?noredirect=1#comment50678850_31347414), the OP's goal is to figure out which words were used based on which **string positions** were used, rather than which **letters** were used -- so the word/substring `THROW` is basically irrelevant.

Here's a very short version:

```
from itertools import chain

wordlist = ["ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR"]
string = ''.join(wordlist) # "ONETWOTHREEFOUR"
stringpositions = [6,7,8,0,4]

# construct a list that maps every position in string to a single source word    
which_word = list(chain( [ii]*len(w) for ii, w in enumerate(wordlist) ))

# it's now trivial to use which_word to construct the set of words 
# represented in the list stringpositions
words_used = set( which_word[pos] for pos in stringpositions )

print "which_word=", which_word
print "words_used=", words_used
```

==>

```
which_word= [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
words_used= set([0, 1, 2])
```

**EDIT:** Updated to use `list(itertools.chain(generator))` rather than `sum(generator, [])` as suggested by @inspectorG4dget in the comments.

Comment: I like the list solution - very straightforward. Though, I might have used `list(itertools.chain(...))` instead of `sum(lists)`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, that's a good point. `sum(lists, [])` is kind of hacky but I've been using it since way back in the day and it's really ingrained in me :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the easiest way. If you want to be more space-efficient, you might want to use some sort of binary search tree

```
wordlist = ["ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR"]
top = 0
inds = {}
for i,word in enumerate(wordlist):
    for k in range(top, top+len(word)):
        inds[k] = i
    top += len(word)

#do some magic
L = [6,7,8,0,4]
for i in L: print(inds[i])
```

Output:

```
2
2
2
0
1
```

You could of course call `set()` on the output if  you wanted to

Comment: So this is constructing a dictionary mapping every string index to its corresponding list item? That makes sense. I guess one could also do it with a list, since there's little functional difference between a list and a dictionary where the keys are integers. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Sam, that's correct. [My answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/31347886/20789) does it with the list instead of with a `dict`.